# how to set a post method in bonita to submit external forms

Tags: post, groovy, bonita, business-process-management

I want to write a post method when an external form in Bonita needs to be executed.
in the other words when click on the submit button,
A post method is called. I do not know how to write and call that method.
sorry for poor English

Answer (score 1):

In Bonita, when a form is associated with a task you can add to it a button and configure the button with the action "Submit task". In the button configuration you can also configure the data to send when the user click the button and the URL to load if the task is successfully submitted.

Clicking on the button will actually trigger a POST request sent to Bonita Engine providing the data input by the user and asking for the task execution. You can view the request in your web browser developer tools.